# How to stop Microsoft Office from removing Personal Information automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-word

So I know how to disable Microsoft from removing personal information on a per document basis, but I want it to be **standard** on all documents without having to repeat the steps per document.

Thanks,

Matthew

Comment: MS Office is a suite. I've never tried to manipulate Word, Publisher, Excel, Access, Outlook at the same time. Interesting question. Tried Google? It might not be possible. You might have to start with Word, Options. Then Excel Options and so on each program in the suite. The program options, not a document manipulation. Tried that yet?

Comment: Also, check, File -> Account, to make sure that you have your account set up. That could be a contributing factor.

Comment: @ejbytes Yeah, I have been googling with no success. However I did read something that an account that was a specific type, it wouldn't automatically remove person data from file on save (Authors and stuff). I think it was more of a business account. So I might just have to have that type of account.